# How to create Category Wise Serial Number in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can we create a Category wise Serial number. Suppose I have 3 Category A,B & C. A has 3 Subcategories X,Y & Z while B has 2 Subcategories X,Y and C has no subcategory. Now on submit if have selected A and subcategory X then it would generate AX0001 and on selecting B with subcategory Y will be BY0001 and on selecting C it would generate C0001. How can we generate this serial number without checking at the database level for Duplicacy?

Comment: not sure if this is what you are looking for but here is my take, fetch the entry with the latest serial number of the given type , example : the highest serial number starting with AX if A category and x sub category is entered and insert +1 to the serial number and category

Comment: the number you want to post-fix after category & subcategory concatenation, need to be checked from DB to avoid duplicate entry. I am still not clear with your requirement

Comment: I need a way in which I don't need to check the DB Table for duplicate entry. For eg: If AX0001, BY0001 & C0001 are entered the next entry would be AX0002 AX0003 and so on ... same with other category.. If there is any other way, do I need to design separate table for this or I can manage by code..??